# UIPageViewController with Constant Elements (that don't move on swipe)

Tags: ios, uiview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm creating a full screen image viewer for my app (i.e. click on a thumbnail and a full-screen viewer opens up that allows for zooming (UIScrollView) and swiping to the next image).  I'm currently presenting the UIPageViewController as a modal view.  I can't seem to figure out how I can place a "Close" button on the screen so I can dismiss this modal view.  I tried to include the "Close" button on the UIPageViewController's content pages but these items move with each swipe (as they are supposed to).  So, how can i create a button that sits above the UIPageViewController and allows me to close this view?

Seems like a simple issue but can't seem to find a good solution.

Comment: Create a new UIView and add it to the screen instead of your UIPageController's view.  Then add your UIPageController's view to this new UIView.  Then add any further static features to this new UIView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding the `UIButton` to the `UIPageViewController` which as you stated would move along with page swipes, do this:

1. Create a UIView
2. add the UIPVC to the newly created view as a subview
3. also add the UIButton to that newly created view as a subview too.

Now you have two subviews in this newly created `UIView` and they would be separate views that you can interact with without it affecting the other

What you were doing before was adding the `UIButton` to the `UIPVC` **which is not what you want** as explained in the opening paragraph

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what is UIPVC ?

Comment: `UIPageViewController` @NgocLK I just abbreviated it to avoid having to write the entire name.